# Manually Create PHP Page For A Redirect

Tags: php, redirect, wp-redirect

I am new to wordpress and working on something for a friend, I have FTP access, and am trying to upload a php file, that checks the platform and redirects the user either to the iTunes store if they are on an iOS device or force downloads a file if the user is on any other platform. I have the PHP file written, but it looks like wordpress pulls all it's information from a database and inserts it into templated pages. I need for users to just be able to access this page unless someone knows of a better method of doing this in wordpress. I need some help, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think more context is in order. How are users accessing the download, for example?

Comment: I'd recommend instead using javascript to do the check, it works better with caching mechanisms

Comment: well the idea would just be the user would click the download link, and from here, I can determine using PHP the platform so, i know if the user needs to be directed to iTunes to download a song for free, or if we can force the download. The problem with using javascript is I still need to set the headers using PHP to force the download, which I can't do using javascipt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are talking about a specific page, for example domain.com/page?
So you can create a generic page template (and select it for the page in WordPress admin panel) or create a template for the specific page. See instructions [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/#creating-a-custom-page-template-for-one-specific-page).

In this template you can add your php code for the redirect.

If this redirection would be done for the whole site, not just one page, you can always edit the generic page template or the header.php file.

Comment: this did work for me. I really appreciate the help! I need to dig deeper into wordpress. thanks again!